# Is $S= \{x:x(\omega)\geq 1,x\in C(\Omega)\}$ closed or compact where $\Omega$ is a compact metric space?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, compactness

Suppose we equipped the Banach space $(C(\Omega),\|\cdot\|_\infty)$ with the norm topology(uniform topology) where $\Omega$ is a compact metric space. According to the definition of topology, $C(\Omega)$ is both a closed and open set at the same time. Moreover, $C(\Omega)$ is not compact because it is not even bounded, i.e. $d(f,0)$ is not bounded. (Am I right on the compactness?). I further consider a subset such that $S= \{x:x(\omega)\geq 1,x\in C(\Omega)\}$ where $\omega\in \Omega$ is a given element. Is the set closed or even compact? How about $S= \{x:x(\omega)\leq 1,x\in C(\Omega)\}$ and $S= \{x:x(\omega)= 1,x\in C(\Omega)\}$

Comment: The Arzelà-Ascoli theorem gives a necessary and sufficient list of conditions for a set of continuous, real values functions on a compact metric space to be compact.

Comment: closed as a subspace of what space?

Comment: @Mirko  as a subset of $C(\Omega)$

Comment: What is $\Omega$? "the space of continuous functions on $\Omega$", that **is** $C(\Omega)$ itself? Or do you mean that same set but in another topology? etc. etc.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma   $C(\Omega)$ is the space of continuous functions on a compact metric space $\Omega$ with uniform norm topology.

Comment: @Mirko For example, $S = \{x:x(\omega)\geq 1, x\in C(\Omega)\}$ is a subset of $C(\Omega)$. I want to know whether this is closed or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S = \{x: x(\omega) \ge 1\}$ is indeed closed in $C(\Omega)$ because the norm topology is finer than the pointwise (product) topology.

Note that $e_x: C(\Omega) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $e_x(f) = f(x)$, is a continuous map for any $x \in \Omega$, because again $|e_x(f) - e_x(g)| \le \|f-g\|$ and so $e_x$ is even uniformly continuous, and $S = e_\omega^{-1}[[1,\infty)]$, the inverse image of a closed set of the reals under a continuous function, hence closed.

Similarly $\{f: f(\omega) = 1\} = e_\omega^{-1}[\{1\}]$ is also closed.

The first is never bounded, as it contains all constant maps with values $c \ge 1$ which is an unbounded subset of $C(\Omega)$. The second one is never bounded if $\Omega$ has more than 1 point. (If $p \neq \omega$, let for each $c \in \mathbb{R}$, $f_c$ be a continuous function on $\Omega$ with $f_c(p) = c$ and $f(\omega) = 1$ (Urysohn functions will do, but it's even easier on a metric space domain), the $f_c$ are in $S$ and unbounded). In both cases $S$ is not compact.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.1.  In your argument of closeness. The evaluation function you defined is continuous in the uniform topology so that $S=e_\omega^{-1}[[1,\infty)]$ is closed. Am I correct? Is the evaluation map also continuous in the point wise topology?  2.  I just learn Arzelà-Ascoli theorem. Can you give me an example of subset of $C(\Omega)$ that is compact?  I am looking forward a subset of function that is equicontinuous, pointwise-bound and closed.

Comment: 3. I am also got a little confused in your first sentence. I understand that norm topology is finer that the point wise topology. Why this fact implies $S=\{x:x(\omega)\geq 1\}$ is a closed set?   I think you flow of logic is that $S=\{x:x(\omega)\geq 1\}$ is closed in the point-wise topology hence it is also closed in norm topology.  so why is $S=\{x:x(\omega)\geq 1\}$ closed in the point-wise topology? Or, what is the open set in the point wise topology?

Comment: @Ethanabc the pointwise topology is the smallest topology that makes all $e_x$ continuous. That’s why all your example $S$ are both pointwise and uniformly closed.

Comment: @Ethanabc $\Omega=[0,1]$, define $f_n(x) = \frac{x}{n}$ then $\{f_n: n \in\mathbb{N}\} \cup \{0\}$, where $0$ is the constantly $0$ function, is an example of a compact subset of $C(\Omega)$.

Comment: equicontinuous and pointwise bounded is trivial based on the definition. The set is closed because the every sequence has the same limit, which is 0 function. Hence it is closed. Hence by Arzela-Ascoli theorem, it is compact. Is that true?

Comment: @Ethanabc yes, but even easier: it’s a convergent sequence together with its limit. This is compact in any space.